# How can I get a honeycomb pattern onto these faces

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

Im making a tire for a vehicle as seen in the picture below and the rim of the tire is composed of a honeycomb. How can I achieve this? I have tried tessellation, Dual mesh and shrinkwrapping/boolean a honeycomb i made yet none of them give me the effect i want [image]

Im thinking of using a rotated empty with array though im sure theres an easier way

Answer (score 1):

Create your segment (front view):

[image]

Array it on X:

[image]

Create an empty at the same position, rotate it 90° on Y, give your honeycomb object a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, *Angle* > a bit more than 360°, *Origin* > select the empty, *Axis* > choose Y:

[image]